# Measuring elapsed time over network

Tags: c++, time

I have developed a server and client application for streaming video frames from one end to another using RTSP. Now, in order to gather statistics which will assist me in improving my applications, I need to measure the elapsed time between sending the frame and receiving the frame.

At the moment I am using the following formula:

```
Client_Receive_Timestamp - Server_Send_Timestamp = Elapsed_Time
```

**Problem**

It seems to me that the elapsed time is about 100-200ms too high. I think the reason is that the server clock and client clock are not in sync and have a difference of about 100-200ms.

**Question**

How can I accurately measure the elapsed time between the two mashines?

The topic [Accurately measuring elapsed time between machines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21078805/accurately-measuring-elapsed-time-between-machines) suggests calculating a round-trip delay. However, I can't use this solution as the client doesn't request the frames. It simply receives frames via RTSP.

Comment: Could you clarify why you can't calculate a round-trip delay? Are you forced to use the RTSP stream as your only network connection? If not, you could use simple pings over a different network connection to estimate the round-trip time.

Comment: Use third machine and confirm your doubts.

Comment: @LukasBoersma My goal is to measure how long it takes to deliver the frame, not to measure how long it takes to send and receive a single packet.

Comment: @Islamon That's not a solution. The third mashine could also not be in sync.

Comment: Right, but if you can measure how long it takes to send and receive a single packet, you can estimate the round trip time, which in turn allows you to estimate the difference between the system clocks, which in turn allows you to fix the formula you posted.

Comment: @LukasBoersma How do I get from a ping (=round trip delay) to the difference between the system clocks?

Comment: You send the current time to the second machine. When you receive it there, add half of the round-trip time to estimate the current time on the sending machine. Do it multiple times and take the median to reduce noise. For details, look at the [NTP protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Time_Protocol#Clock_synchronization_algorithm), which does basically that.

Comment: I'll try to implement that later today or tomorrow. You can post it as an answer, then I'll accept it once it worked out fine for me.

Comment: Note that RTSP ([RFC2326](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2326)) is a protocol for establishing and controlling media sessions between end points - not for transporting the media stream itself.  The media stream is often (but is not required to be) transported using the RTP transport protocol ([RFC3550](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3550)), whose companion control protocol RTCP (in the same RFC) specifies (among other things) means of reporting transit delays to the origin endpoint, taking into account issues like scalability.  Well worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming

- you want to measure only the latency of the one-way trip
- each machine provides a [clock of acceptable resolution](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock)
- both clocks can be [synchronized to acceptable accuracy](http://www.ntp.org/)

then you can simply subtract the "sent timestamp" from the "received timestamp" to obtain the latency duration. The [observed error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observational_error) will be less than the sum of both clock errors. If the time scales are small enough (probably anything smaller than an hour) you can reasonably ignore [slew](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slew_rate) effects.

If `ntpd` is not already running on both machines, *and* if you have the necessary permissions, then you can

```
$ sudo ntpdate -v pool.ntp.org
```

to force a synchronization with the pool of publicly-available time servers.

Then you can use the c++11 `high_resolution_clock` to calculate the duration:

```
/* hrc.cc */
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int main(int,char**){
  using std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
  // send something                                                                                                                      
  high_resolution_clock::time_point start = high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout << "time this" << std::endl ;
  // receive something                                                                                                                   
  high_resolution_clock::time_point stop = high_resolution_clock::now();
  std::cout
    << "duration == "
    << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(stop-start).count()
    << "ns"
    << std::endl
    ;
  return 0;
}
```

Here's what the previous example looks like on my system:

```
$ make hrc && ./hrc
c++     hrc.cc   -o hrc
time this
duration == 32010ns
```

Answer (score 3):

> I need to measure the elapsed time between sending the frame and receiving the frame.

You don't need precise timestamps for this. You can average the estimated latency.

If A sends the packet (or a frame) to B, B responds immediately<sup>(*)</sup>:

A<sub>(sendTime)</sub> ---> B ---> A<sub>(receivedTime)</sub>

then you can calculate the latency easily:

```
latency = (receivedTime - sendTime) / 2
```

This assumes of course that the latency is symmetrical. You can find more elaborate algorithms if you research "network latency estimation algorithm" phrases.

Having the estimated latency you can of course estimate time difference (but it doesn't seem necessary):

A<sub>(sendTime)</sub> ---> B<sub>(receivedTimeB)</sub> --<sub>(receivedTimeB)</sub>--> A

```
timeDelta = sendTime + latency - receivedTimeB
```

Note that even if you average many results, this algorithm is probably highly biased. This is just posted as a simple example to the general idea.

---

<sup>(*) The fact that it does not happen really immediately induces an error of course. This depends on how heavily machine B is loaded.</sup>

Comment: The problem here is that I can't just respond with a single packet. I would need to respond by sending the entire frame back to the server because it takes longer to transport an entire frame (= multiple packets).

Comment: @Chris. The "ping" packet is irrelevant here. If you can make B respond at once, it doesn't matter what are you sending. You can make exactly the same calculations using frames. So you can perform the measurements online, while transmitting data. Or, if you need to do that before the transmission occurs, you can use N differently sized packets and estimate how fast the latency grows with the size of the packet. This would allow you to estimate the latency of an arbitrary frame size.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. However, the solution mentioned in the comments below the question seems easier to implement.

Comment: @Chris. The solution in comments assumes you know the round-trip time. So it's identical to the solution I've posted at the end of my post (estimating `timeDelta`). Sending `sendTime` is the same as sending "current time".